# Problem integrating flutter module in existing android app

Tags: android, flutter

I am having problems with integrating my flutter module in an existing android app.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating settings 'androidapp'.

  > C:\Users\Akshay Satish\youthPillar-master (1)\flutterapp.android\include_flutter.groovy (C:\Users\Akshay Satish\youthPillar-master (1)\flutterapp.android\include_flutter.groovy)

I am getting the above error after running "gradlew assembleDebug".

These are the errors i am getting in android studio.

ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :flutter.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app

ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :flutter.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app

ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :flutter.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app

ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@release/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :flutter.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app

ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@releaseUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :flutter.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app

Comment: how did you solved this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm glad to see another add2app question.
Sorry about the delay - hopefully you got it figured out by now, but if not - flutter packages get from the flutter module should create this file.

cheers

Comment: I dont understand.can you make it a little more clear?

Answer (score 0):

Close flutter module and your native android project and reopened it for first build.